# Communicating XML content via email / content type / charset?

Tags: php, xml, email, xml-parsing, email-headers

Trying to submit XML data to an email address which is set to collect data for parsing and submission to a local CRM system. Can't seem to find any documentation on what the proper content-type and charset should be set as in the headers so that the data will be parsed properly. Plenty of information on HTTP, but unable to find anything on sending XML via email. Is someone able to point me in the right direction here?

Comment: I should mention, the XML data is being written in the body of the message. For this sort of application, is it more commonplace to attach an XML file, or to include the data in the body? Thoughts?

Comment: Content-Type: text/xml ?

Comment: Tried that. Documentation is showing the text/xml is deprecated, but should work. I revised the headers to include "Content-Type: Application/xml-external-parsed-entity" and "Charset: UTF-8". Awaiting confirmation of receipt from the end user. Fingers crossed!

Comment: Still not working. Still looking for a solution.